# Recursive module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

In a NodeJS 14+ project main JS, how can I recursively export all `.hbs` files?

Tried:

```js
module.exports = () => ({
   partial : __dirname + "/../partial/**.hbs",
   helper  : __dirname + "/../helper/*.js"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```js
module.exports = () => ({
   partial : __dirname + "/../partial/**/*.hbs",
   helper  : __dirname + "/../helper/*.js"
});
```